# Regex group by finding one of two repeating groups

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I want to sort this into groups of 1s and groups of zeros

```
    var string = '10011110000100101';

    var matches = string.match(/0*|1*/gi);

    console.log(matches);
```

I currently get

```
 ["", "00", "", "", "", "", "0000", "", "00", "", "0", "", ""]
```

Expected output:

```
 ["1", "00", "1111", "0000", "1", "00", "1", "0", "1"]
```

The 1s aren't being grouped, and are showing up blank.

If I switch the one and zero, the opposite happens:

```
["1", "", "", "1111", "", "", "", "", "1", "", "", "1", "", "1", ""]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `*` quantifier for both `0` and `1`. `*` means "*match the preceding token **zero** or more times*". The regex matches an empty string, and that's reflected in your final output. To fix this, you can use `+`, which means "*match the preceding token **one** more times*".

```
/(0+|1+)/
```

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/bP4bX7/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use `+` instead of `*`:

```
   var matches = string.match(/0+|1+/gi);
```

The problem is that `0*` matches a `1` in the string.